# Advice needed: Processing data edits on a blazor server app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm not sure, if it is the best way to send every data edit on my web app through the WebAPI. In my environment there is a WebAPI running between the business logic an the client application which is a Blazor server app.

It seems that there are too many triggers where the client must react to data inputs of the users, so it could be that the WebAPI gets quite busy, if more users are online.

To perform validations and serveral data lookup operations I now have to send a request to our WebAPI every time anything does change via UI. Is there a better way to get rid of this mircro requests or is it the best way I am doing now.

One example is the setup of an address record.
The user selects a country from a combobox, at the next datacontrol, the user should only be able to enter a region of the prior selected country. In the listed elements of the input control, only regions of the country are allowed to be listed. Therefore I now perform a request to the Web API to get the correct regions for the country. When leaving the combobox I'Ve to send another request to validate the input.

Does there any best-practice guide exists, or is there any pattern i should consider to use.

Comment: It is prefered to keep the entire business logic on server side. I think it might be necessary due to mobile client apps which will be developed in future.

Comment: Yes, I am with you. At the moment I'm not sure if it good to implement the entire functionality via API. It mainly costs time (and nerves). The second question which appears is, that I do not have any experience, how much it will affect the performace of the hosting server. The App will targeting up to 25 Users who are permanently using the application.